# SyntaxError Unexpected token to end a argument list

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code:

```
$('#form_step_2').validate({
        customer_credit_card_number: {
            required: true,
            creditcard: true
        },
        customer_credit_card_expiration_month: {
            required: true,
            range: [1, 12]
        },
        customer_credit_card_expiration_year: {
            required: true,
            range: [new Date().getFullYear()+1, new Date().getFullYear()+16]
        },
        customer_credit_card_security_number: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 4
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('Success');
    }
});
```

All looks working except an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.
```

I think the error is at this line

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
```

But when I look the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) of jQuery validation plugin I use, it looks correct.

Any help please ?

Comment: If you look at the docs closer you'll see that there's a `{` before `submitHandler`.

Comment: Check your braces. The ` }, submitHandler:` bit closes your first object, then declares a named parameter. JS doesn't have those, so it fails.

Comment: @Juhana, check the docs closer too. Look at the last example of my link.

Comment: `$(".selector").validate({
  ignoreTitle: true
});` ? How is that relevant? (although that starts with a curly bracket too)

Comment: `rules: {` was missing at the start from the docs...

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra closing bracer there, edit as follows:

```
$('#form_step_2').validate({
    customer_credit_card_number: {
        required: true,
        creditcard: true
    },
    customer_credit_card_expiration_month: {
        required: true,
        range: [1, 12]
    },
    customer_credit_card_expiration_year: {
        required: true,
        range: [new Date().getFullYear() + 1, new Date().getFullYear() + 16]
    },
    customer_credit_card_security_number: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 4
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('Success');
    }
});
```